# How does sidekiq prevent multiple workers from taking the same job id's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

If I have multiple servers acting as sidekiq works, how does sidekiq ensure that when it polls redis it doesn't give 2 servers the same job to process?

Can someone point to the codebase as I really want to understand what is going on under the covers.

Comment: I'm not sure it does. Sidekiq best practices say that jobs should be idempotent and that you should assume that all jobs will execute *at least once*.
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#2-make-your-job-idempotent-and-transactional

Comment: Meaning that each job has to check if it has already processed already?  I don't think that is what is meant by idempotent.

Comment: No, I think it means that the system should be able to assume that all jobs could be run repeatedly without issue.

Comment: @MaxWoolf yes agreed makes sense.  But I want to know if it will hand out the same job to 2 different workers on 2 different servers.

Answer (score 5):

BRPOP is atomic, it pops an item off the list and handles it to a caller.  If a list has three elements, 1000 callers can call brpop at the same time.  Three callers will get an element, the other 997 will block, waiting for an element.

https://redis.io/commands/brpop

Comment: props to brpop!

Comment: do the workers poll or is there is socket/consistant connection to redis?

Comment: Both.  They block for 2 seconds at a time.  Sidekiq maintains a connection pool of open sockets to Redis. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#connection-pooling

Comment: But what about this line in sidekiq wiki [`Just remember that Sidekiq will execute your job at least once, not exactly once.`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#2-make-your-job-idempotent-and-transactional)? Is that a reference to retrays?

Comment: Retries.  Yes, that's one way.

Comment: @MikePerham what would be other potential ways?

Comment: Sidekiq Pro can rescue and re-execute orphaned jobs (jobs lost when a Sidekiq process is killed).